# Option to close a question

Tags: discussion

I'd like an option to close or delete a question that I asked by this motivation:

"The matter was resolved by other means than following the answers. "

Or similar rationale. Since sometimes the answers are good and there can be 2 answers to a question and the problem in the question was resolved not by doing what the answers suggest but by some other activity that solved the problem.

Or is what should be done in these cases, is answering your own question?

Comment: Please interpret the downvotes as a poll on the solution you proposed, not a reflection on your decision to ask about it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Are you saying that two clicks make some statistics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Post an answer that details what you did to solve the problem, and accept it. It's no different than if someone posted your steps as an answer, and then the answer is there for someone with a similar question later.